# A quadrilateral with one pair of opposite right angles. Is this a rectangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I can prove it's not a rectangle by drawing some lines, but is there a name for this kind of figure? Thanks.

Comment: Can you draw it for us?

Answer (score 1):

It's only a rectangle if the other opposite pairs of angles are also right angles. However it is a cyclic quadrilateral since opposite pairs of angles add to 180 degrees.